# How to set new password with jax-rs when running under java webstart?

Tags: java, jax-rs, java-web-start, jersey-2.0

I'm connecting to my rest service using Jersey and JAX-RS in my Java webstart application. When the user changes their password using my webstart application I then reset the `WebTarget` with a new `HttpBasicAuthFilter` with the new password... however, the new password does not get used!!! I've run the same code locally outside Java webstart (with `java` instead of `javaws`) and it works fine. Here's the problem code:

```
public WebTarget getWebTarget(String username, String password) {
  Client client = ClientBuilder.newBuilder().sslContext(SSLContext.getDefault()).build();
  client.register(new HttpBasicAuthFilter(username, password));
  WebTarget targetBase = client.target("localhost");
  return targetBase;
}
```

The password above will not change the underlying password that is used when the `WebTarget` is used with something like `request().get()`. I know the code works because if I launch with `java` instead of `javaws`... it works! So the problem is in the java webstart, which seems to be caching the password.

How do I get a new `WebTarget` to the same address/host with a different password and the same username?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not Java webstart, per se. The problem is that Java webstart supports cookies and therefore session data. The service on the backend is Grails and is storing that the user was authenticated in a session cookie... and therefore as long as that cookie is valid the backend will work and new passwords are simply ignored.